# Change Back Link of Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I wanted to know if there's a way to change the `Back` link in my app.

My app is built like this : The first view (`Oil`) is a tableView inside a Navigation Controller. 
There's 3 button at the bottom, `Oil`, `Property`, `Application`. So if I tap on the first one (`Oil`) it does'nt change anything as we are already on this view. If I tap on the second button which is `Property` the view goes on an other Navigation Controller and an other tableView is displayed.

[image: Orange Link]

But Now if I tap on a cell in my tableview Property it brings me back to the `Oil` view. I perform a Segue, and with this segue I set my Navigation Bar Title as the Property name.

**PropertyViewController.m :**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PropDetail"]) {
        OilViewController *test = segue.destinationViewController;
        test.propName = propertyName;
    }
}
```

**OilViewController.m :**

```
if (_propName) {
    self.title = _propName;
    /* Imaginary Code 
        back.link = PropertyView;
    */
}
else {
    self.title = @"
}
```

This works If I go to Property View and then tap on a property I "go back" to the `Oil View` and the title is for example *Dream*. But the problem is that when I click on the `Back button`it brings me back to the Real `Oil View`. Instead of this I want the back button to go back to the PropertyView.

Can I change that in the code and how ? Thanks. I know I could just duplicate my code, or built my app in an other way, but I'm almost done and I don't want to start from scratch again.

I hope I was clear, Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unwind segue to back to any view controller you want. Check out this question
[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

Comment: This is not what I want. I'm not using Button, but Back button in Navigation